# Unwanted highlight of element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a dot navigation but when I click one time under the third dot or at the left of the three dots there is a redish box highlighting, I already tried `user-select: none` or even the `::selection` property and put the background color to transparent but the highlighting still remains, would there have any other css property or method that could cancel that?

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    document.getElementById("event").addEventListener("click", e => {
        const allItems = $('#event > li');

        for (let i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
            allItems[i].classList.remove("is-active");
        }
        e.target.classList.add("is-active");
    })
});
```

```css
html{
user-select: none;
}

::selection{
background-color: transparent;
}

.is-active{
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: red !important;
}

#vertical-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
 #vertical-nav ul > li {
  background: black;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
 #vertical-nav ul > li a {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 13px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 #vertical-nav ul > li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: lightgrey;
}
 #vertical-nav ul > li:hover a {
  //opacity: 1;
}
 #vertical-nav ul > li:hover a {
  //opacity: 1;
}
 
 ul > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="vertical-nav">
        <ul id="event">
          <li>
            <a data-number="1">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a data-number="2">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a data-number="3">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with java. Please don't add it back

Comment: @adiga didn't see I had put java sorry for the mistake and thank you for the edit

Comment: Side note: `//` doesn't start a comment in CSS. You have to use `/* ... */`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah forgot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are adding the event listener to the whole container. You should target only the bullet. Since you are using jQuery you can also simplify your code:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#event > li").click(function() {
    $('#event > li').removeClass('is-active')

    $(this).addClass("is-active");
  })
});
```

```css
html {
  user-select: none;
}

::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.is-active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: red !important;
}

#vertical-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#vertical-nav ul>li {
  background: black;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#vertical-nav ul>li a {
  opacity: 0;
  float: right;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 13px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#vertical-nav ul>li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: lightgrey;
}

#vertical-nav ul>li:hover a {
  //opacity: 1;
}

#vertical-nav ul>li:hover a {
  //opacity: 1;
}

ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="vertical-nav">
  <ul id="event">
    <li>
      <a data-number="1">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-number="2">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-number="3">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what grey area?

Comment: @SimpleDev - Oh. Okay. That doesn't seem to be the problem you were describing. BTW, if you want to keep using event delegation as you originally were: `$("#event").on("click", "li", function(e) { const allItems = $(this).siblings(); /*...*/ });`

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Run the snippet and put your mouse *just left* of a circle. The circle turns grey. Since the OP talked about grey, not red, I assumed that was the problem they wanted to solve. Apparently not. (The OP has now edited the question to say "reddish.")

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank for your answer, mplungian already wrote the jquery code, btw I wasn't talking about the hover selector that turns the point grey

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see. this is due to the hover effect in the CSS over the link element that is taking more space than the li since it contain the text inside and its hidden

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, there was a text at the left of the point but for demonstration purposes, I decided to make it of opacity: 0;

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery all the way and not check the click on the UL

The issue with your code was that you add is-active to the UL when clicking next to the LI

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#event li").on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("is-active");
    $(this).addClass("is-active");
  })
});
```

```css
html {
  user-select: none;
}

::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.is-active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: red !important;
}

#vertical-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#vertical-nav ul>li {
  background: black;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#vertical-nav ul>li a {
  opacity: 0;
  float: right;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 13px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#vertical-nav ul>li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: lightgrey;
}

#vertical-nav ul>li:hover a {
  //opacity: 1;
}

#vertical-nav ul>li:hover a {
  //opacity: 1;
}

ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="vertical-nav">
  <ul id="event">
    <li>
      <a data-number="1">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-number="2">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-number="3">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll use this simplified jquery version

Answer (score 0):

simple css solution would be

```
a.is-active{
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: red !important;
}
```